# How to list data from two different worksheets on a third depending on a month selected?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet named "Payments" where I would like to list all the names which are in the lists in worksheets "Main" and "Canceled", depending on the month selected in "Payments".
Both lists in "Main" and "Canceled" have "Names" in one column and "Date paid" in other, and the chances are those list will have blank cells somewhere in them.

My Excel experience is certainly lacking, so I'm not sure if there is a simple answer to all of this.
My first step was to merge both lists on another worksheet called "Data", but for some reason combining 4 columns of data ("Names" and "Date paid" from "Main" and "Canceled") into two was more troublesome for me than it probably should have been, so I never even made it to any other step...

If worksheet "Main" looks like this: [Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ycj4.jpg)
And worksheet "Canceled": [Canceled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ywul.jpg)
The list on sheet "Payments" should simply look something like this:
[Payment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhfg7.jpg)

I'm using Excel 2013 if that changes anything.

I would certainly appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Possibly through a Pivot Table, with some tinckering :)

Comment: @JvdV Ah, thanks, I'll try if there's no simple solution with formulas

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data and the expected output so we know what you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: @TerryW I've provided a couple of pictures that hopefully explain enough

Comment: I think there will be no simpler formula-based solution than using pivot table. Let me know if you are unable to get the desired result using pivot table.

Comment: I actually did  it with a formula. I've put both lists (from "Main" and "Canceled") one underneath other, on a worksheet "Data".  
And there I used array formula 
 =IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$200;SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$200=$C$1;ROW($B$1:$B$200)-ROW($B$1)+1);ROWS($B$1:$B1)));"")